# ¿Como accedo a un objeto desde $request en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, requests

Hola a todos de ante mano gracias por sus respuestas y opiniones cualquier tipo de orientación es bien recibida.
Tengo el siguiente problema desde mi front le envio datos a mi controlador en formato de objeto, en mi función, en el objeto $request al hacer un **return $request** obtengo la siguiente estructura:

```
    {
      "tableName":"catalogos",
      "fields": [
                  {"name":"nombre","number":50},
                  {"name":"edad","number":50}, 
                  {"name":"apellidos","number":50}
      ]
   }
```

Para accerder a **tableName** lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
return $request->input('tableName'); // me devuelve catalogos
```

Para acceder a fields lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
return $request->input('fields');
```

Me devuelve esto:

```
[
    {"name":"nombre","number":50},
    {"name":"edad","number":50},
    {"name":"apellidos","number":50}
]
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Como accedo a los campos de fields es decir a name y number?

Lo que quiero lograr es crear una tabla en mi base de datos aunque no es el objetivo principal de mi pregunta pero hago mención para que se entienda mejor lo que quiero lograr.

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
           
            $tableName = $request->input('tableName');
           
            if (!Schema::$tableName) {
                Schema::create($tableName, function($table) use ($request)
                {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    foreach ($request['fields'] as $item) {
                        $table->string($item, 'aquí quiero agregar number');
                    }
                });

            }
            
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Catalogo creado exitosamente',
            ], 200);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Gracias por sus repuestas y comnetarios cabe mencionar que no puedo usar los modelos ya que el problema no me permite otra opción más que la que planteo.

Comment: Probá hacer un ```foreach ($request->input('fields') as $field) { dd($field->name); }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La estructura de fields es un array de objetos, así que hay que recorrerlo.

```
foreach($request->input('fields') as $objs)
{
  $name = $objs['name'];
  $number = $objs['number'];
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @David Tapias, no parace funcionar la implementación que me propones me arroja lo siguiente message":"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: Oh! ok, lo interpreta como array, ya vi la solución, pequeña confusión.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me base en ella para resolver mi duda, me ha sido de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hola a todos logre resolver con las repuestas y comentarios que me han escrito gracias a todos los que intentaron ayudar, les comparto como me funciono.

```
foreach($request->input('fields') as $item)
{
  $name = $item['name'];
  $number = $item['number'];
}
```

Solucionando el problema en general que había planteado al final de mi pregunta.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        function convertSnake($data) {             
        
            $snake_case = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($data));
            
            return $snake_case;        
        }
        

        $tableName = convertSnake($request->input('tableName'));
       
        if (!Schema::hasTable($tableName)) {
            Schema::create($tableName, function($table) use ($request)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                foreach($request->input('fields') as $item) {
                    $table->string(convertSnake($item['name']), $item['number']);
                }
            });
        }
        
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Catalogo creado exitosamente',
        ], 200);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```